# How can i use a container for the left margin and container-fluid for the right margin in html element?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a whole page aligned with bootstrap container class, and in the footer i'd like to align the inner content as well, but i'd also like to expand the container till the end of the screen as a container fluid would do, that way i can put some extra elements, here is a schema of what id like to achieve.

here is my code right now

```
<!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="footer mt-4 ">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <h4 >Información</h4>
                    <p class="titulo">Horario de atención al publico</p>
                    <p>Lunes a viernes: 8:00h a 20:00h</p>
                    <p>Primer domingo del mes: 8h a 13:30h</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <p>Central de recepción de pedidos</p>
                    <p class="titulo">lorem ipsum)</p>
                    <p>Teléfono: lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid custom-container">
            <div class="row justify-content-end">
                <div class="col-lg-4"  >
                    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d50423.74877919936!2d-1.7035813695033786!3d37.61417570140527sdfoijaslkdfjslfdgjlsadkfjgñlshj!5e0!3m2!1ses!2ses!4v1555406807431!5m2!1ses!2ses" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </footer>


    <!-- /Footer -->
```

that's what id like to achieve
[i drawn something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f9pu.jpg)

Comment: I don't think that's very intuitive, why not just set a left-margin without the container?

Comment: Because the whole page is already aligned with container and i need the footer to be aligned with all the sections in the page

Comment: Can you share your full code replicating what you currently have in a snippet?

Comment: I'm trying the code you provided, and I understand what you mean, but I fail to see the reasoning behind sticking with `container` classes, please explain a bit more with a more complete example demonstrating the issue so we can help

Comment: I think you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56778466/right-aligned-bootstrap-container-which-also-aligns-with-default-container